# deleteAllVisibleCookies fails with error in playframrwork selenium webdrive

Tags: selenium, playframework, webdriver

I have two selenium tests:

```
#{selenium 'test1'}    

    deleteAllVisibleCookies()

    openAndWait('/url1')

#{/selenium}

#{selenium 'test2'}    

    deleteAllVisibleCookies()  // HERE IT FAILS!

    openAndWait('/url2')
#{/selenium}
```

Second test says to me that '**Couldn't delete cookie context**'

How can I fix it?

I use [webdrive](http://www.playframework.org/modules/webdrive) module for playframework in order to user real browser resting. This particular test is working for firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it like this:

```
#{selenium 'test1'}
    deleteAllVisibleCookies()
    openAndWait('/url1')
#{/selenium}

#{selenium 'test2'}
  openAndWait('/')              // +
  pause(1000)                   // +
  deleteAllVisibleCookies() 
  openAndWait('/url1')
#{/selenium}
```

A bit stupid, but it works.